# How can I place several ImageViews side by side?

Tags: android, xml, listview, imageview

Ok, so I am trying to create a layout that has side by side image views in a listview. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3FLD.jpg) would be an example of what I'm trying to achieve. However, I'm really not sure how I should be doing this. Here is an example of what I have found online. The problem is that once you start adding more imageviews it just adds them to the same line and not below the current ones.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingTop="15dip"
          android:paddingBottom="15dip">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/numberDays"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitStart"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:src="@drawable/placeholder1" />
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/placeholder1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitStart"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:id="@+id/daysText"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Would a listview be a better method of displaying these images side by side or should I be doing it with XML as such?

Comment: please use gridview to achieve this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: If the number of images is not fixed, ListView or RecyclerView is better. I recommed you to use RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager. Here is example http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use grid view for this and use this

android:numColumns=" " in your gridView xml.

Comment: I'll definitely try it out and report back.